# Using two enums in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, swift5

I have two enums `Items` and `Filters` as

```
enum Items: Int {
    case ItemA = 0,
    ItemB,
    ItemC,
    ItemD,
    ItemE

}


enum Filters: Int {
    case FilterA = 0,
    FilterB

}
```

I need to have the Items enum to be in Int.
And I am trying to implement `Filters` enum so that:

`Filters(0).filter()` returns `[ItemA, ItemB]`

`Filters(1).filter()` returns `[ItemC, ItemD, ItemE]`

`Filters(0).count()` returns `2`

`Filters(1).count()` returns `3`

Enums in swift is so much different than how I know enums from C... Can't get a grasp. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems `Filters` may not need to be an enum at all, just some static vars. What are they for and how do you intend to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors and bad practices in your code.

1. An enum name must be sigular
2. An enum case name should begin with a lowercase letter
3. An enum case name should not contain the name of the enum itself (eg. `a` instead of `ItemA`)
4. The filter and count methods IMO should be added to the `Item` enum
5. The filter and count methods should receive a `Filter` value, not an `Int`
6. You are free to manually assign `0` to the first case but this is not needed because the compiler will do it for you
7. IMO `Condition` is a better name for the `Filter` enum

### Solution

Here's my solution

```
enum Condition: Int {
    case a, b
}

enum Item: Int {

    case a, b, c, d, e

    static func filter(with condition: Condition) -> [Item] {
        switch condition {
        case .a: return [.a, .b]
        case .b: return [.c, .d, .e]
        }
    }

    static func count(with condition: Condition) -> Int {
        return filter(with: condition).count
    }

}
```

### Usage

```
Item.filter(with: .a) // [a, b]
Item.filter(with: .b) // [c, d, e]
Item.count(with: .a) // 2
Item.count(with: .b) // 3
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you for the to-the-point explanations :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you can find this useful:

```
enum Items: Int {
    case ItemA = 0,
    ItemB,
    ItemC,
    ItemD,
    ItemE
}

enum Filters: Int {
    case FilterA = 0,
    FilterB

    func items() -> [Items]? {
        switch self {
        case .FilterA:
            return [Items.ItemA, Items.ItemB]
         case .FilterB:
                return [Items.ItemC]
        }

        return nil
    }

    func count() -> Int {
        return items()?.count ?? 0
    }
}

let filter = Filters.FilterA

filter.items()
filter.count()
```

you can instantiate filter enum like this also:

```
let filter = Filters(rawValue: 0)
```

---

FYI swift cases should start with lowercase by the book, I left them uppercased to do not creat more confusions compare to your question code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like static data a simple solution would be to keep the different sets of enum elements in a dictionary. And I agree with another poster that the naming of your enum could be better

```
enum Item: Int {
    case a, b, c, d, e
}

let itemFilter = [0: [Item.a, Item.b]], 
                  [1: [Item.c, Item.d, Item.e]]

if let filter = itemFilter[0] {
    print(filter)
    print(filter.count)
}
```